# In macOS, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate panes in the Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

Ian macOS, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate among Terminal.app's split panes within a window?

Comment: By the way, I'm aware that iTerm support this kind of navigation already. 
I'm looking to keep using the vanilla MacOS terminal.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing. The panes in Terminal.app simply give another view on the scrollback buffer of the same terminal, you can't put "focus" on them with your mouse or keyboard.

The panes in iTerm (and others such as VS code) run actual separate terminals in each pane, allowing you to switch to them.